# Как запретить пользователям делиться своими логином/паролем для входа на сайт?

Tags: веб-программирование, login

Интернеты я прошерстил, решения не нашёл.

Дано: есть сайт с платным доступом. Предполагается, что пользователь покупает себе "билет на одно лицо" и пользуется инфой на сайте. Задача в том, чтоб с этим "билетом" смог зайти только он один и никто другой.

Вход по паре логин/пароль отметается сразу - кому мешает поделиться этой парой с кем бы то ни было и разделить оплату за пользование сайтом на 50 человек. Целевая аудитория заходит в 90% случаев с мобильных телефонов. В том числе с айфонов. Локальный файл не создашь. От куков толку нет - айфон  периодически обновляет софт, стирая все данные. Фингерпринты как вариант, но тоже обнулятся при апгрейде. Смс подтверждения или что-то наподобие гугл-аутентификатор не катят, первичный покупатель сможет делиться ими с наследниками, хотя и могут его задолбать и он отошьёт половину своих людей, но не факт. Авторизация через госуслуги или через гугл-аккаунт нежелательна, ибо будут пользователи не из России и айфонщики без gmail.

Задача: позволить вход на сайт только одному оплатившему. Или максимально усложнить процесс кооперации. Можно ли через сайт получить доступ к отпечатку пальца?

Одно может радовать - пользователи нихрена не хакеры, встречаются даже такие, кто не может капчу пройти. И это не бабульки-пенсионеры, им это не надо.

В качестве оправдания - я не мошенник, не вымогатель, и проч. Людям действительно нужна инфа с моего сайта и никто их не принуждает.
Просто пытаюсь монетизировать свой софт.

Comment: USB-токен с неизвлекаемым ключом в единственном экземпляре. Правда, воткнуть его в айфон вряд ли получится...

Comment: А можно ссылку на ваш сайт, или хотя бы узнать его тематику

Answer (score 0):

В общем и целом на 100%, да еще чтобы исключить ложные срабатывания (когда не пускают настоящего покупателя) - никак.
Можно использовать разные механизмы, чтобы как-то усложнить совместное использование.

- двухфакторная авторизация.
- отслеживать откуда входит пользователь (если в течение дня из трех разных городов, и так на продолжении нескольких дней, то вряд ли это один человек).
- запретить более одной активной сессии.
- другое что-нибудь.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что никак. Даже у крупных сервисов, например apple tv, многие скидываются вскладчину на семейную подписку. Минимальная защита - это привязка устройств(например максимум 3 в месяц), и регистрация через сервисы к которым привязывается номер телефона(например ВК).

Возможно стоит посмотреть в сторону персонализации контента, то есть чтобы контент на вашем ресурсе, алгоритмами подбирался под предпочтения пользователя, и тогда ему просто не будет смысла делиться с другими